# Error when delete exist file then create file again

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I'm writing a combine all excel, csv files into 1 merged file program. Everything works fine until I want to delete exist merged file then call the function to re-create the merged file again. Does anyone know how to fix it?
Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
files_directory = askdirectory(title='Select Folder')
merged_file_name = "merged" #merged file name
files_extension = [".xlsx",".csv"] #files_extension
if files_directory != '': #if merged file directory is selected then:
    for ext in files_extension:
        files = os.path.join(files_directory,"*"+ext) #select file extension statement
        all_files = glob.glob(files) #load all files include detail path into all_files list
        merged_files = os.path.join(files_directory,merged_file_name+ext) #generate full meged file name
        def mergeExcelCsv():
            if ext == ".xlsx":
                df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(a, header=None) for a in all_files], ignore_index=True)
                df.to_excel((merged_files), index=False) #save .xlsx to same location
            if ext == ".csv":
                df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(a, header=None, sep=',') for a in all_files], ignore_index=True)
                df.to_csv((merged_files), index=False) #save .csv to same location
            else:
                pass
        if os.path.exists(merged_files):
            filename_only = os.path.split(merged_files)[1] #select file name only
            message = filename_only + " already exists, do you want to overwrite it?"
            msgbox=messagebox.askquestion("Files exist", message, icon='warning')
            if msgbox == 'yes':
                os.remove(merged_files)
                messagebox.showinfo('File overwrite', 'This file is overwritten!')
                mergeExcelCsv()
            if msgbox == 'no':
                pass
        else:
            mergeExcelCsv()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: And the error was: https://i.imgur.com/PDR8yfC.jpeg

Comment: The variable `all_files` isn't updated when you call `mergeExcelCsv` so it's using the old list of files when the file you deleted was still there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by added variable `all_files` again before I call `mergeExcelCsv` to update the new list.

```
if os.path.exists(merged_files):                            
            filename_only = os.path.split(merged_files)[1] #select file name only
            message = filename_only + " already exists, do you want to overwrite it?"
            msgbox=messagebox.askquestion("Files exist", message, icon='warning')
            if msgbox == 'yes':
                os.remove(merged_files)    
                messagebox.showinfo('File overwrite', 'This file is overwritten!')
                all_files = glob.glob(files) #Update all files after deleted               
                mergeExcelCsv()
            if msgbox == 'no':
                pass
        else:
            mergeExcelCsv()
```